# Consults in the same program with excel and sql databases

Tags: sql, json, excel

i have this homework to do, but i just dont know how to attack the problem, i need to make a program in python that can make consults between an excel database and an sql database in the same program without changing the database my teacher say that i can use json but i dont know how to do it, i dont want the code, i just need the tools for solve the problem thank you

Comment: Homework questions are welcome here so long as **you show original effort and ask a specific question**.

Answer (score 0):

If you do end up using python, I would recommend [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) for reading and writing to an Excel sheet, and [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) to connect to your database. I find this combo quick and intuitive to use.

Comment: Asking to recommend an outside resource or library is literally a specific reason to close a question as off topic.